# Tokyocabinet: loop to traverse of the BTree file

Tags: c, loops, tokyo-cabinet

I traverse the BTree by cursor ([example from documentation](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html#tcbdbapi) )

See code bellow:

```
 kkey_t* p2;  // the type kkey_t is some struct
 int counter=0;
 BDBCUR *cur = tcbdbcurnew(bdb);
 tcbdbcurfirst(cur);
 while((p2 = (kkey_t*)tcbdbcurkey(cur, &len )) != NULL){ 
    printf("%u.%u\t%u\n",p2->type, p2->key, counter);
    free(p2);
    res = tcbdbcurnext(cur);
    if (!res) break;

    counter++;    
 }
```

I get the 562 418 records by  `tcbdbrnum()`, 
but I have loop where `counter` is more that 150 000 000 and more...
I d't have cycle finish.

What is the problem can be?

I find that the loopsize is 150652 cylses and loop offset nearly 1.3 * 150652 
So, I increase file to 1 042 638 keys, and I have loopsize = 280299
The ratio recsize / loopsize = 3,73...

What to do, that have unlooping?
Why I have the looping?

The all keys is random of size 64 bit (8 bytes).
The some keys caould be deleted.

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize `counter`?

Comment: I have tcbdbrnum() = 562418, so I find that looping is on the 150652

Comment: The size of loop is 150652 items, offset is nearly 150652 + 150652/3 items

Comment: if I have 1042638 keys, I have loopsize = 280299